# Dual Screen problem when trying to maximize the window on the second screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Today I bought a monitor and started using dual screens: one is my laptop's screen, other one is the monitor I bought. Everything seems fine so far except one thing and that is: if I try to maximize the window on the second screen, system automatically carries the window to the first screen and maximizes it on the first screen. I cannot have fullscreen windows on the second screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what application do you want to put fullscreen?
for example, in libre office impress you can choose under slide show > slide show settings > multiple displays.

Comment: @Presbitero for now, I need chromium, gedit and remmina remote desktop client (I am planning to put the remote desktop connection window to the second monitor)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround I found on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/751605).  It works for me:

> **If you want to maximize on left screen:**
>
> 1. Drag your window in the left monitor, with your mouse (normal size)
> 2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
> 3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>
>
> **If you want to maximize on right screen:**
>
> 1. Drag your window in the right monitor, with your mouse (normal size)
> 2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>
> 3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

According to the page, there is a fix (patch for Compiz).  I just don't know where/how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this again, now with a second monitor.

I don't have Unity on my laptop as I use cinnamon, so I tried with gnome classic and I get the same problem as you did.

The best workaround that I found was not to use remmina but rdesktop with the resolution option '-g WxH', using the width and height of your second monitor and then drag the window to it.

Also, if you are interested, in cinnamon it works with remmina as long as you manualy choose the resolution to fit the one of your second monitor.